# CSS navigation drop down menu -- don't want width set

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this HTML:

```
 <div id="wrap">
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><%= link_to('home', '/') %></li>
  <li><%= link_to('about', :controller => 'about') %>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><%= link_to('meet & greet', :controller => 'about') %></li>
      <li><%= link_to('work with me!', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
      <li><%= link_to('contact', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><%= link_to('recipes', :controller => 'recipes') %>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><%= link_to('Breads', :controller => 'about') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Breakfast', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Brownies', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Cakes', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Cookies', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Cupcakes', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Donuts', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Gluten Free', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Healthy', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Lunch', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Muffins', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Misc.', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('No-Bake', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Pasta', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Pizza', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to('Savory', :controller => 'contact') %></li>
  </ul>
  <li><%= link_to('everyday', :controller => 'blog', :action => 'everyday') %></li>
  <li><%= link_to('development', :controller => 'blog', :action => 'development') %></li>
</ul>
```

```
#wrap   {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
    z-index: 99; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
    position: relative;
}

.navbar {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    position: absolute; /* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
    margin-left: 142px;
}

.navbar li  {
    height: auto;
    width: 110px;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
    float: left;  /* This lines up the menu items horizontally */
    text-align: center;  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
    list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar a   {
    padding: 10px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */
    text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
    color: #686868;
    display: block;
}

.navbar li:hover, .navbar li a:hover, .navbar ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #7BCDC8;
    color: white;
}

.navbar li ul   {
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
    height: auto;
    margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
    padding: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
}

.navbar li:hover ul     {
    display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
    color: white;
}

.navbar li ul li {
    background-color: #7BCDC8;
}

.navbar li ul li a  {
    border-left: 1px solid #7BCDC8;
    border-right: 1px solid #7BCDC8;
    border-top: 1px solid #7BCDC8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7BCDC8;
}

.navbar li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #7BCDC8;
    color: white;
}
```

I want to remove the width of the list item and just set padding-left/right to 15px so that they are even distance apart. When I do that, the drop down no longer works. Any helpful tips?

Comment: Please describe "no longer works". Also, you are referencing the width of the `li` elements, not `.navbar`, correct?

Comment: Correct. It breaks the drop down navbar ul li ul li elements.

Comment: tried using (important) on your css to force the style on the element?

Comment: @eddwinpaz I'm not sure what you're trying to help with there... It has nothing to do with the property not applying

Comment: To force the style set use width:10px !important; on the class that you want to set the value

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the width by first removing the `float` from `.navbar li`, instead placing it in

```
.navbar > li {
    float: left;
}
```

So that it only affects the top level.

But, that leaves you with some [ugly change on hover](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/G7KRu/), which you can fix by putting

```
.navbar ul li { padding:0; }
```

Which prevents the padding from applying on lists within lists (doubling the amount). [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/G7KRu/2/)

However, I do not recommend removing a set with from the drop downs because doing so creates [ugly and varying widths](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/G7KRu/1/) of the list elements because of the different lengths of the words

Also remember to close your `li` tags, you missed one for `<li><%= link_to('recipes', :controller => 'recipes') %>`

Comment: Thanks! Thought I responded to this way back when.

Comment: @Christina If an answer is acceptable you can mark it as correct by using the check mark to the left of the answer :) It gives both uses reputation for doing so